# Save the image from the picturebox

Tags: vb.net

Use this code to save the image from the PictureBox.
By saving the file and adding a name to it
The problem I'm facing, come on, when adjusting the image the following error occurs : -  a generic error occurred in gdi+

My Code

```
show image

Using fs As New System.IO.FileStream("path", IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read) PIC_PARTA.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fs)  End Using
```

```
save image
   Dim pic As Image
            pic = PIC_PARTA.Image
            Dim Savefild As New SaveFileDialog
            Savefild.FileName = TEXT_NAMEIMG.Text & ".PNG"
            Savefild.ShowDialog()
            pic.Save(Savefild.FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
            LAB_path.Text = Savefild.FileName
            Savefild.Dispose()
            pic.Dispose()
```

Comment: 1. You should only save the image when `SaveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK`.  2. You need to verify that `PIC_PARTA.Image` is a valid `Bitmap` object. 3. You aren't reassigning `pic` before calling `Dispose` so you're actually disposing the current image in the PictureBox which you shouldn't do. 4. You shouldn't call `.Dispose` directly, use a `Using` block instead. 5. Add a `Try/Catch` block to gracefully handle errors.

Comment: I did all this.
The problem is that the image file is running

Comment: What do you mean by "The problem is that the image file is running" ?

Comment: I am fetching the image path from the database and importing the image into the image box.
And I want to amend the image with the same file and the same name as re-writing on the image file. This is what is required, hence the error.

Comment: "And I want to amend the image with the same file and the same name as re-writing on the image file" - I still don't understand what you mean. That doesn't have anything to do with `pic.Dispose()`.

Comment: How EXACTLY are you loading the `Image` in the first place?

Comment: hi  jmcilhinney .  '\\ Using fs As New System.IO.FileStream("path", IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read)
                            PIC_PARTA.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fs)
                            'fs.Close()
                        End Using

Comment: Don't post code in comments. It's hard enough to read when it's formatted but yours isn't even that. Even if it wasn't code, no one should have to read the comments to understand the problem. All information relevant to the problem should be in the question, so edit it to include that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a full answer at this stage but it includes a significant amount of code, so I'll post as an answer and then either update or delete as required.

I just tried this code and all four saves worked, even though I thought that some may not:

```vb
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Private ReadOnly folderPath As String = Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyPictures, "Test")

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(Path.Combine(folderPath, "Picture1.png"))

        Using fs = File.OpenRead(Path.Combine(folderPath, "Picture2.png"))
            PictureBox2.Image = Image.FromStream(fs)
        End Using

        PictureBox3.ImageLocation = Path.Combine(folderPath, "Picture3.png")

        PictureBox4.Load(Path.Combine(folderPath, "Picture4.png"))
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            PictureBox1.Image.Save(Path.Combine(folderPath, "Output1.png"))
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Try
            PictureBox2.Image.Save(Path.Combine(folderPath, "Output2.png"))
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Try
            PictureBox3.Image.Save(Path.Combine(folderPath, "Output3.png"))
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        Try
            PictureBox4.Image.Save(Path.Combine(folderPath, "Output4.png"))
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
        End Try
    End Sub

End Class
```

Can you please test that with your own images in your own folder and see if you get the same result?

Note that the `Image.FromFile` option locks the file until you dispose the `Image`. I have seen instances in the past where trying to save an `Image` created using `Image.FromStream` generates the error message you mentioned because it can't access the stream again later. `Image.FromFile` avoids that but has its own downsides.

My code that uses a `FileStream` directly is simpler and, therefore, better than yours but setting `ImageLocation` or calling `Load` is simpler again and thus better again. I suggest that you use one of those two options and see whether you still have an issue.